# Create ROLE with Terraform in AWS with SAML provider attached

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, terraform, amazon-iam

I'm currently trying to automate AWS account provisioning, and one the steps is to create IAM ROLE, with Identity provider(for federated user access). 
I searched, and checked Terraform documentation, but cannot find any information about creating such role, or attaching provider to a role. 
I can create both just fine, but they are independent.
here is portion of the code:

```
resource "aws_iam_saml_provider" "default" {
  name                   = "ADFS-TEST"
  saml_metadata_document = "${file("../../FederationMetadata.xml")}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
    name = "test-Admins"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

figured out. here is full block

```
resource "aws_iam_saml_provider" "test" {
  name                   = "ADFS-TEST"
  saml_metadata_document = "${file("../../FederationMetadata.xml")}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
    name = "ADFStest-Admins"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "${aws_iam_saml_provider.test.arn}"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF

}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "admins" {
    name        = "Admin-Policy"
    #description = "A test policy"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.role.id}"
    policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! It works for me.

I just change aws_iam_role_policy to use the aws_iam_role_policy_attachment:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach" {
    role = "${aws_iam_role.role.name}"
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
}
```